# "Abnormal program termination" bug in the D2007 IDE : is there any workaround?

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-2007

I face a very annoying bug in D2007 IDE :

It's the second time I have this problem within one month (on two differents computers, but with the same project), and it is a very annoying bug that causes the IDE to close itself without allowing me to save any changes in the code.

I tried but cannot reproduce the bug, it only appears randomly.

Here's what happen exactly :

i'm changing a line of code then (when I press "enter" to go next line)
the message

**"Assertion failed: amount >= dest - startDest, file ek_flbuf.cpp, line 315"** appears.

and when I press OK an second message "**Abnormal program termination**" appears.

Closing this message cause the IDE to quit.

When googling at my problem i found QC 33917 but the status is **Closed : Cannot Reproduce**

My questions are :

- Is there any known workaround to this problem ?
- can this problem be caused by third party stuff ? (I'm using GExperts and Delphi SpeedUp)
- Does anyone here encountered the problem on a more recent IDE ?

***UPDATE :***
I remembered the problem occurs the first time (a month ago) within the same Unit.
so maybe the problem is not only project related but unit related.

I've restarted Delphi and returned in the same function where the problem appears today, trying to reproduce the bug only typing some code then deleting it, again and again, like a mad...

just restarting delphi and editing code in the unit (no other actions before), **I managed to reproduce the problem a second time today !** but no more, despite many new similar tentatives... :(

...still investigating. (and thank you for the answers, I will now stop trying to reproduce the bug and check the answerers hints.)

Comment: You have observed the issue two times with the same project. Do you remember if you had *run* your project (through the debugger) since the RAD Studio was started at both times?

Comment: @Andreas : I've updated the question, for the third time I was sure I have not run the project before the bug appears. (don't remember for the first time, and Yes I ran the project this morning before the bug appears (hitting F9 with debug mode on)

Comment: Interesting that you see such problems only on occasion. I've seen such crashes multiple times per day when dealing with borland IDEs (last one was BDS2006), and just learned to live with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I used 2007 and saw this, it only happened on very long units (10,000+ lines - having that many is an issue for another discussion :p)  Usually the IDE would be fine, then typing would become fairly slow - I could see the letters I typed lagging behind in the code editor. Unless I paused and let the editor catch up, I'd get that error.

So, my fix was:

- If you're in a large unit and the editor starts lagging, **pause**, immediately.  Let it catch up, and keep going.

This is really annoying, but worked for me.

I also turned off many of the Code Insight features, but I don't know if they affected this particular issue or not.  They did help general editing speed.  Turning them off was recommended to me in the then-Codegear forums.  I can't remember who by, but I have a vague feeling it may even have been one of the Codegear QA staff who was aware of the bug but was trying to see if I could narrow down what affected or caused it.  This was a couple of years ago now though, so don't take that as gospel.

Splitting your files into smaller, say <5000 line units may also help.  For me it only happened on large and complex files.

The issue seems to have been fixed in RAD Studio 2010.  Another way to avoid the error would be to upgrade :)  If you do, wait a few days or talk to their salespeople first.  The next version, [RAD Studio XE](http://www.embarcadero.com/rad-studio-xe-preview), is due out at any moment.  I'd recommend upgrading anyway: you'll need to handle Unicode issues, but other than that the 2010 edition is the best version I've used, including its stability, and I've used Delphi since version 1.

Comment: thank you for feedback, the unit where I experimented the issue is 28350 lines... (the biggest unit of this project, in fact.) I also think now that the problem can be "error insight" related, because I remember I had some false errors reported for this unit (unit not found, etc.) the last time I experimented the bug. Then restarting after the IDE crash, and after a pause (go make a coffee..), simply hitting space in the unit makes all "error insight" problems disappear... and then, impossible to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 4):

The last time I have seen this, is when one of my source files had inconsistent line endings.

Make sure all your lines in all your source files end with CRLF.

--jeroen

Comment: ok i will check this, I had such problems in the past (when pasting code from other programs..) that cause breakpoints misplaced. I do not have the breakpoints problem now, but I think it worth rechecking this.

Comment: Does anybody has a tip for quickly searching bad lines ending within delphi (an expert, or a trick with Search (ctrl+F) menu ?).
I ask this because my project has more than 800 files to check... and I really want to make sure my problem is not related to this..

Comment: @DamienD: It would not be hard to write a Delphi program that searches all files in a directory for 1) CRLF, and 2) LF not preceeded by CR.

Comment: @DamienD, do yourself a favour and by a decent regex tool. Powergrep and the accompanied RegExBuddy are (IMO) unmatched for a very fair price.

Comment: @Lieven : I will check this. But I started writing a delphi progam as suggested. At the moment it works but is sloooow (reading files byte by byte..) and didn't found any CRLF problems. I consider turning it into a delphi expert (and learn about building experts at this occasion)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to try is to remove both add-on packages (GExperts and Delphi Speedup).  It could be something they are doing.

The second is to do your best to reproduce and submit the issue.

The third is to upgrade to a new version of Delphi and hope that it solves your problems without creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

If this happens on two separate computers, but the same project on both, then the problem is most likely in the project itself and not the IDE. Of course, you didn't post any of the code that causes the error message to appear, so it's hard to help you find out what the problem is with the code. I find it very unlikely that the problem is the IDE, though, or others would have reported the same problem (D2007 has been out and in use by millions of developers for years now).

If the problem is in the IDE itself, you should be able to reproduce it with a new, empty project. Copy and paste only enough of the code from the old project into the new one to allow the problem line to compile, and then replicate the same change->press Enter to add a new line - does the same assertion failure and then abnormal termination happen?

If you can't reproduce the problem in a new project, the problem is most likely with your code, and without seeing it it's hard to tell what might be causing it.